# Overriding method in ruby module for testing?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

How do I override methods in a module?

Comment: There are a number of answers for this specific case in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215245/ruby-unit-testing-how-to-fake-time-now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put your new method in later on in the code. For example, if this is the module (somefile.rb):

```
module M
  def some_method
    # ...
  end

  def get_time
    time = Time.new
    return time
  end
end
```

Put this in the file that needs the module:

```
require "some_module"

module M
  def get_time
    time = Time.parse("07/09/10 21:22")
    return time
  end
end
```

Comment: @Mo: Yes. And this extra sentence is to pad the comment with content so stack overflow doesn't get mad about a short comment.