# How do you test models that depend on Date.current?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My model will have logic that uses Date.current like this:

```
if(date_three && date_three != Date.current.yesterday)
  ...
end
```

How do I change the system's current date on my specs so I can test my model with different dates?

Comment: Pass in the date to test against as a dependency, don't hard code it. This will allow your tests to select a date to test against, and other methods can pass in `Date.current`.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215245/ruby-unit-testing-how-to-fake-time-now - Google "ruby testing time" first result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a gem for just this kind of tasks - the [timecop gem](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop).